# ArcPy Cursor does not fill new field?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, cursor, fields-attributes

I am working with a point shapefile, for which I have created a new field *NEW_ID*. This represents a unique code for each point. This is more convenient to me than using the *OBJECTID*.

I want to fill the new field with the values coming from the following list:
`myvalues=range(1000000,1002332)`

And I am trying to get this working, but the field is still `<Null>` after the snippet has run:

```
myFeatureClass=r'C:\temp\testGDB\test_shp'
cur = arcpy.UpdateCursor(myFeatureClass)

for row in cur:
    row.setValue('NEW_ID', row.getValue(myvalues[row]))
    cur.updateRow(row)
```

I suspect I cannot use `row` as an iterator. So, what should I use instead?

---

ArcGIS version: 10.3.1

---

Comment: What is the exact error including line number that you get when you run the precise code snippet that you have presented?  What version of ArcGIS are you using?  I ask because if you are using 10.1 or later I would recommend forgetting about the old style cursors and switch to ArcPy.da.

Comment: Oddly enough I am not getting any error, but then again the field is empty. I am using ArcGIS 10.3.1.

Comment: Your myFeatureClass variable does not seem to be set to a valid pathname for either a geodatabase feature class or a shapefile.

Comment: Yes, I set that in such a dumb way to avoid showing personal information. The shapefile is inside a `.gdb` container, but posting the real path wouldn't have made this problem reproducible anyway.

Comment: Yes, `row` is an object,  not a radix, but you really ought to start over from scratch usimg `arcpy.da.UpdateCursor` which uses a different syntax structure (and is 8-20 times faster). The new `row` will be an array of column values, so you still need to create and increment a radix value. I expect there are dozens of questions very similar here by now.

Comment: A shapefile ***cannot*** be within a geodatabase container -- they are two completely different formats.

Comment: To anonymize a feature class I always copy it to C:\temp\testGDB\testFC and then write my code snippet against that.

Comment: Making a reproducible snippet is the "service charge" associated with getting free help from GIS SE. Please put in an effort to make standalone code (it might even solve the problem before you post it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is how you get your new ID number from your list `myvalues`. You are using your whole row object as an index which clearly makes no sense.  As @PolyGeo suggests you would do best to use the newer cursors from the da module, they are far faster. But you can use the old ones too.

I assume you have created your list with as many rows as there are in the featureclass, otherwise you would run out of numbers!

If this was me I would have done it this way:

```py
myFeatureClass=r'C:\Myfolder\target_shp'
cur = arcpy.UpdateCursor(myFeatureClass)

newid = 1000000
for row in cur:
    row.setValue('NEW_ID', newid)
    cur.updateRow(row)
    newid = newid + 1
```

Comment: This one I like. But the problem arises when you have an alphanumeric code to assign, instead of plain numbers. Something along the lines of `AA01`, for instance.

Comment: Well you didn't say that! :)

Comment: Yes, I didn't... I thought a general solution involving parsing the list could do for any situation. My bad.

Comment: Well if the code is constant it would simply be: `row.setValue('NEW_ID', "AA" + str(newid))`